# Sum of $k {n \choose k}$ is $n2^{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

Proof that $\suṃ̣_{k=1}^{n}k {n \choose k}$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ is equal to $n2^{n-1}$.

As a hint I got that $k {n \choose k} = n {n-1\choose k-1} $.

I tried solving this by induction but, in the inductive step I'm not arriving to the correct result.

Comment: Factor out the $n$ using given identity and adjust the remaining sum so that you can use the known sum of binomial coefficients.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/388587/321264

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just change the index $s=k-1$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k {n \choose k} = n\sum_{k=1}^{n} {n-1\choose k-1}= n\sum_{s=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose s} =n2^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 10):

> \begin{align*}  &A = \sum_{k\geq1}^{n}k\cdot \binom{n}{k} \\ \end{align*}

$A $ is the no of ways to form a committee of $k \geq 1$ people out of $n$ available individuals and select one head for the selected committee.

Empty committee is not possible. Therefore we select the head first in $n$ ways and then any subset out of $(n-1)$ remaining people in $2^{n-1} $ ways.

> \begin{align*}  &A =n\cdot2^{n-1} \\  \end{align*}

Answer (score 9):

One possible proof:

Because
$$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^k,$$
then by taking derivative,
$$n(1+x)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^n k{n \choose k} x^{k-1}. $$
Let $x=1$, we obtain that
$$n2^{n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^n k {n \choose k}.$$

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this is to differentiate the identity $$(1 + x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k $$ and then put $x = 1$.