# Find the value of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \binom {n} {k}$

Tags: calculus

I was assigned the following problem: find the value of $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \binom {n} {k}$$ by using the derivative of $(1+x)^n$, but I'm basically clueless. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/683733/321264

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$(1+x)^n= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom {n} {k} x^k$$

> $$f'(x)=n \cdot (1+x)^{n-1}= \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \binom {n} {k} x^{k-1}$$
>
>  Whence, we have: 
>
>  $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \binom {n} {k} = f'(1) = n \cdot 2^{n-1}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint: that equality just slipped my mind, but then I managed to solve the exercise by myself.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $\displaystyle S = \sum_{k=0}^{n} k \binom {n} {k}  = \sum_{k=0}^{n}(n-k)\binom {n} {n-k} = n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom {n} {n-k}-S$

so, as $\displaystyle \binom {n} {n-k}=\binom {n} {k}$ we have $\displaystyle 2S  = n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom {n} {k} = n2^n$ and so $\displaystyle S = n2^{n-1}.$

Answer (score 3):

Imagine tossing a fair coin $n$ times. Then the mean number of heads is
$$\sum_0^n k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2^n}.\tag{1}$$
We compute the mean another way. Let random variable $X_i$ be $1$ if we get a head on the $i$-th toss, and $0$ otherwise. Then the number $Y$ of heads is given by 
$$Y=X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_n,$$
and therefore by the linearity of expectation we have
$$E(Y)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)+\cdots +E(X_n).$$
Since $X_i=1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, we have
$$E(Y)=\frac{n}{2}.\tag{2}$$
Now comparison of (1) and (2) gives the result.

**Remark:** This is an example of a *Mean Proof*.

Comment: This is a bit of an overkill compared to my current knowledge, but thank you for teaching me this kind of approach.

Comment: You are welcome. I wrote this solution since there were already proofs of a more conventional kind, and I thought that the connection with probability theory might be nice to mention.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that 
$$
(1+x)^n =  \sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k \binom {n} {k}
$$
and thus 
$$
((1+x)^n)' =  \sum_{k=1}^{n} k x^{k-1} \binom {n} {k}
$$
Now, calculate the left-hand side, and then think which value of $x$ could be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : set $$f(x)=(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k$$ What you get when you evaluate $f'(1)$ ?

Note that you sum can begin from $0$ since the term with $k=0$ is $0$.