# Binomial Theorem general formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, binomial-theorem

I've trying to solve this problem. I just need someone to set me on the right path to solving it.

Given that
$$(1+x)^n = nC0 + nC1x+ nC2x^2 + nC3x^3 + \cdots + nCnx^n$$ 
for all $n$ belong to $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Now I should prove that
$$nC1 + 2nC2 + 3nC3 + ... + n\cdot nCn = n \cdot 2^{n-1}$$
How do I prove this?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Have you attempted an induction proof?

Comment: Differentate and set x = 1

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683733/sum-of-k-n-choose-k-is-n2n-1

Comment: Yes I am trying to prove it by induction