# Prove $\sum^{n}_{i=1}\binom{n}{i}i=n2^{n-1}$ using binomial and induction

Tags: induction, binomial-theorem

Can anyone help? I've got to prove

$$\sum^{n}_{i=1}\binom{n}{i}i=n2^{n-1}$$

using binomial first and then induction.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180181/find-the-value-of-sum-k-1nk-binomnk, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576089/find-a-formula-for-sum-k-1n-k-n-choose-k, and many more duplicates, which can be found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5En%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bi%7Di%24&p=1)

Answer (score 0):

By binomial theorem we obtain: $$\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{n}{i}i=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{n}{i}x^i\right)'_{x=1}=\left((1+x)^n\right)'_{x=1}=n(1+x)^{n-1}_{x=1}=n2^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Can you clarify? I'm new to this and I cannot really understand the second term...

Comment: I used $(x^i)'=ix^{i-1}$

Comment: Taking the derivative?

Comment: Yes, of course!