# How to find $\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How to find the sum of series,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}?$$

I try solve using this fact
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$$
but it didn't help.
And now i haven't some ideas.
Maybe i can calculate $$\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}?$$
using $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k\binom{n}{k}?$$
using this fact
$$\binom{n}{k}  = \binom{n - 1}{k - 1} + \binom{n - 1}{k}$$
I failed use it

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ? [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [How to ask a good question ?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: I yet fix my mistake, i forgot about $ in my formula

Comment: It's important that you share your work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have done a serious attempt to solve it and you're not trying to do others to solve it for you. This is not a homework service.

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics where it have other meanings. Use `\cdot` ($\cdot$), `\times` ($\times$) or ideally, just simply use juxtaposition.

Comment: Ok, i will fix it, and i writed about my reflections

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/894159/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2180181/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/576089/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/683733/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/388587/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Combinatorial argument**

To make a basket team, you need players, and among these players, you need one captain. So, $k\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of team with $k$ players you can make among $n$ people. Therefore, $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of team you can make with $n$ people. But to make a team, you can also take one person among the $n$ people, and say that it's the captain. You have $n$ possibilities to choose it. After, you can decide if each of the $n-1$ other people are in the team or not. So at the end, you can make $n2^{n-1}$ teams. Therefore $$\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{n}{k}=n2^{n-1}.$$

---

**Using Binomial formula**

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k=(1+x)^n.$$
Therefore, \begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{n}{k}&=\left.\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d x}\right|_{x=1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k\\
&=\left.\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d x}\right|_{x=1}(1+x)^n\\
&=n2^{n-1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: one more elementary method will be the one using $k\binom{n}{k} = k\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = n\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!((n-1)-(k-1))!} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ for $k\ge 1$. Then use the binomial formula.